# NativeScript - Clickable Span not supported

Tags: android, ios, vue.js, nativescript, clickablespan

Even though `Clickable Span` is not supported in {N}, but is there any workaround for this?

I have read the following thread but still don't really know how to implement on NativeScript-Vue, may anyone help, please?

[Feature request: ClickableSpan support for iOS and Android](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/3671)

Answer (score 0):

Nothing changes with Vue except the fact everything will be JS and event handlers will follow Vue syntax.

[Here](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=zNNInf&v=2) is the Vue implementation of the same demo project. I was able to test it on Android, not having access to iOS device ATM. Let me know in case if you hit any issues.

**Update:**

Updated playground link with fixes for iOS